# IPC with Forms?

Tags: forms, delphi, ipc, blocking, message

I want to make IPC, but I cannot use blocking mechanism (SendMessage, PIPE, TCP), and I don't wanna use Threads (more source of errors), or storing the data (files, registry for example).

Here is 2-4 softwares in every PC, and I want to synchronize the "message existance".

What is it? I explain it.
Every app is uses same database. They are periodically read the "messages" with two queries, and see when "normal" and "alarm" message arrived - or when they are all opened and read.
But one of them are the "chosen", protected with mutex, and it control a trayicon, and balloon hint. When message arrived, it reflected on tray.
When this app die, another trying to get the mutex, and control the tray.

I want to use the IPC to say the "master" if the state changed (new message arrived, or all messages read) to master know about this, and we avoid this situation:
Master show the tray and balloon, and user read the messages in another app. In this case the master don't know about it, and continue to show the "new messsage" controls. Or master read all, but a new message arrived. In this time the master must inform about this.
Because the checking periods are: normal message - 5 minutes, alarm - 2 minutes.

So: why I don't use blocking IPC, like SendMessage?
Because if the master starts a big query (5 minutes) then the another apps are blocked for these time.. :-(

Previously I tried with temp files, registry writing, but every of them is have the problem of "cleaning", so data remaining...

Then I have an idea the every form is visible for "EnumWindows". If messages are stored in Title, I only do PostMessage with the Handle of this form, and the Master can read the Title, process the message.
If 15 minutes passed, we ignore this message, and the "message" window destroyed.

Ok, ok, it is don't elegant, but I don't know about any way that don't store anything in files, and cannot block (async) - without threading hell.

```
proc Send(Info : string):
  handles = EnumAndFindHandles();
  for handle in handles:
    o = CreateMessageForm(handle, Info);
    PostMessage(WM_MYMSG, handle, 11111, integer(o.Handle));

proc Recv(var Msg):
  if IsHandleValid(Msg.lParam) and ClassNameIsGood(Msg.lParam):
    txt = ReadWindowText(Msg.lParam);
    if txt > '':
       ...
```

I want to know two things:
1.) Do you know any situation when this communication can failed? (Caption is missing, changed or other thing that can blocking this way)?
2.) As I see only the Forms can visible in EnumWindows? Do you know a way to do this with another control?

Thanks for any ideas, good informations, suggestions!

dd

Comment: Doesn't sound like a right design approach. Check our MsgConnect product, it does what you need simply -- you use SendMessageCallback or SendMEssageTimeoutCallback method and send the message asynchronously. You can send messages on the same computer or across network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it sounds like [memory mapped files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2006/01/30/519483.aspx) could be a simple solution: share a block of memory between your applications, just like with a temp file. You said you considered file-based methods but don't like the traces they leave. With memory mapped files the traces will be in the page file, which might not be such a big deal as with the registry or temporary files.

Comment: When you share data with a memory mapped file, also consider using a semaphore to lock the resource during content update (if it is not a read-only content). With concurrent access of the same memory mapped file, it is very easy to go into a race condition or share conflict, just like in a multi-threaded application.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [StateLess aproach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) instead.

Here are some benefits:

- It does not require any server side pushing of the updates;
- You do not need to wait for timeout or communication issue: clients refresh themselves on need (e.g. with a timer);
- It scales very well in a Client-Server approach (on both sides);
- Threading architecture model is cleaner: the client can use the main GUI thread, and each server connection can have its own thread in a stateless approach;
- The whole web (via the StateLess HTTP protocol) is using it - so you can communicate with HTTP, which is much more network friendly than other protocols.

Even if you still need local IPC yet, consider moving to a network-friendly architecture may make your future easier. It also prepare your application to move to [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) if needed. For instance, our [stateless Client-Server ORM](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) is able to communicate locally with GDI messages (as you propose) or named pipes, or remotely using HTTP/1.1.